# Wrong version of keystore on android call

Tags: java, android, certificate, bouncycastle, keystore

I want to make a https request.

I use bouncycastle to generate the keystore like this :

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias ludevCA -file lu_dev_cert.crt -keypass mypass -keystore keystore.bks -storepass mypass -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar
```

And the keylist command return a correct value.

But when i do :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);  
ks.load(in, "mypass".toCharArray());
```

i have a error :

```
wrong version of keystore
```

I tried to use several version of bouncycast, but the result is the same. I also tried to define keysize 1024, but nothing change.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't forget to use SHA-256, cause SHA-1 is no more used with android 23+, and is by default...

Answer (score 31):

You need to change the type of the keystore, from BKS to BKS-v1 (BKS-v1 is an older version of BKS). Because the BKS version changed as said [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/security-enhancements-in-jelly-bean.html)

There is another solution, that is much much easier:

1. **Using Portecle:**

- Downloads Portecle http://portecle.sourceforge.net/
- Open your bks file with the password and portecle
- Do Tools>>Change Keystore Type>>**BKS-v1**
- Save the file

2. **You may use [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)**

The new file will be encoded with BKS-v1 and will not show the error anymore. To change the KeyStore type, open KeyStore Explorer and go to `Tools -> Change KeyStore Type` and then save the file.

**Note:**
Android works with different BKS versions: for instance, API 15 will require BKS-1 contrary to API 23 which requires BKS, so you may need to put both files in your app.

You can use this code to switch between them depending on the API level:

```
int bks_version;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    bks_version = R.raw.publickey; //The BKS file
} else {
    bks_version = R.raw.publickey_v1; //The BKS (v-1) file
}
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(bks_version);  
ks.load(in, "mypass".toCharArray());
```

Comment: seemed to fix an issue i was having for a 4.0.4 device, but devices with 4.1.1/2 are still having the same issue

Comment: Don't know why but when I tried to change it with Portecle, it just kept on disallowing me to change the keystore because it says  unrecoverablekeyexception. But then I tried it out with Windows and Keystore Explorer and changed the keystore type from there and it worked like a charm. +1

Comment: Workaround for 4.1.1/2: ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { ... } ```

Answer (score 4):

Finally i used a graphic editor (KeyStore Explorer) under Windows and it's working.

Maybe the error was caused by Java/Mac version problems

Answer (score 4):

Solution is Here , able to remove the version prolem

Creating BKS file for android client

Software installation details required to create BKS file:

Download Keystore Explorer software from link http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/

Download UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Extract zip and copy US_export_policy and local_policy to your C:/programes file/java/jre7/lib/security folder.

install  Keystore Explorer software.

Steps to Generate  BKS file: (Need CA file , Certificate file , Key File and .P12   i.e.PKCS file(if available).

1) Creating Trust file using  CA .crt file using keystore software.

Steps:

Open software
Go File->New->select .BKS from the wizard
To import CA certificate file Go Tool->Import trusted certificate ->select CA .crt file -> entert password->(It will throwa an exception if certificate is self sign) import file  forcefully.

4.Save file with .bks extension.

2) Creating Key file using  .P12 file using keystore software

Steps

Open software
 Go File->New->select .BKS from the wizard

Import >p12 file Go Tool -> Import key pair -> select PKCS #12 from wizard - >enter decription  password for file and brows file -> Enter alise name(if want to change else can keep as it is) ->Enter new password

Save file with .bks extension.

3) Creating Key file using  if .P12 is not available file using keystore software

Steps

Open software

Go File->New->select .BKS from the wizard
Import >p12 file Go Tool -> Import key pair -> select OpenSSL  from wizard - >unchecked decription  password for file ,brows .key and .crt (Certificate file not CA) file -> Enter alise name(if want to change else can keep as it is) ->Enter new password

Save file with .bks extension.

Copy both file in res/raw folder(Both BKS file are compulsarry).

Code:

```
 static final String ENABLED_CIPHERS[] = {
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
    "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
    "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
};
// put this in a place where it can be reused
static final String ENABLED_PROTOCOLS[] = {
        "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1"
    };

   private void sslCon()
    {
        try {
                             // setup truststore to provide trust for the server certificate
              // load truststore certificate
            InputStream trustStoresIs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_ca);
            String trustStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
            trustStore.load(trustStoresIs, "spsoft_123".toCharArray());
            //keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            // initialize trust manager factory with the read truststore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(trustStore);

            // setup client certificate
            // load client certificate
            InputStream keyStoreStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_cert_key);
            KeyStore keyStore = null;
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "your password".toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
            keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "your password".toCharArray());

            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)context.getSocketFactory();
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.11.104");
            sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(serverAddr, 5212);
            //String[] ciphers = sslSocket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
            sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ENABLED_CIPHERS);
            // put this right before setEnabledCipherSuites()!
            //sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(ENABLED_PROTOCOLS);
            //InputStream inputStream =  sslSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sslSocket.close();


        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this answer to provide a cmdline-version for converting a `.pkcs12` File to `keystore.bks`

What is needed:

- Portecle - download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/

If you don't know how to generate a `.PKCS12` -File check out these sites:

- http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2016/01/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-ssl-but-were-afraid-to-ask/
- https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

For this Sample I use `jetty.pkcs12` as source.
The command generates: keystore.bks
/usr/local/share/java/portecle-1.9/ is the path where I've installed the downloaded Portecle-Tool (.ZIP)

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 \
-srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype BKS -providerpath \
/usr/local/share/java/portecle-1.9/bcprov.jar -provider \
org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider-destkeystore \
keystore.bks
```

Now you can use the BKS-Keystore under Android

Thanks to the prev posting I was able find a solution and to provide this cmd. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
```

or

```
KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
```