# Wrong version of Keystore on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, keystore, truststore

I have code that creates its own Trust Store in order to connect to a private server.

When I run this on an HTC Desire C with Android 4.0.3 I get the exception: IOException: Wrong version of key store. at:

```
trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
trustStore.load(in, "xxxpasswordxxx".toCharArray());
```

on the last line where it does the load().

When I run the code on the following devices it works fine:

Nexus 7 and Android 4.4.4, Nexus 4 and Android 5.1, HTC One X+ and Android 4.2.2

The APK is the same (and the password is correct) for all devices. Any suggestions as to what I should look to try in order to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to convert your keystore into a pkcs12 keystore.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey yourKeyFile.key -in yourCertKey.crt -out yourPkcs12Key.p12
```

and then use

```
trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
trustStore.load(in, "xxxpasswordxxx".toCharArray());
```

worked for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but as not answered...
For the one still looking, answer is there:
[Wrong version of keystore on android call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117486/wrong-version-of-keystore-on-android-call/33197845#33197845)

Because android 4.03- was using BKS-V1 (older version) and not BKS as the others...