# Error While Generating .bks file

Tags: wso2-iot

I am using **wso2-emm 2.0.1** with ubuntu x64 system. While configuring the product I am getting one error in genrating `.bks` file for android agent certificate.

I've used this cmd:

```
keytool -noprompt -import -v -trustcacerts -alias 'openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in ca_cert.pem' -file ca_cert.pem -keystore emm_truststore.bks -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-146.jar -storepass 'wso2carbon'
```

And the correspoding errror is :

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
>   java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
>   at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you are using bcprov-jdk16-146.jar when creating the keystore?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41427317/504184 I had the same problem. Make sure you use the full path for 'providerpath' As you can see in the above link - I used pcprov.jar that comes with the latest protecle-tool as provider