# Wrong version of Keystore Exception in Android only. Works fine from Standalone Java

Tags: java, android, ssl, openssl

I generated a `keystore file` for self generated cert and tested it using standalone Java application and it works fine. There is just the one `.cert.pem` added to the keystore.  Loading the same file from assets folder of Android and I get the following error:

Wrong version of the Keystore!

Don't see anything wrong it and it works fine outside Android. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117486/wrong-version-of-keystore-on-android-call