# "Wrong version of key store" error. How can I create a version=1 keystore certificate?

Tags: android, ssl, keytool, android-keystore

I am having trouble using SSL, as I am getting the following error related to my keystore (self-created and self-signed using keytool per: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> 08-14 20:55:23.044: W/System.err(5430): java.io.IOException: Wrong
>   version of key store.     08-14 20:55:23.060: W/System.err(5430): at
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(JDKKeyStore.java:812)
>   ...

The error thrown in the `JDKKeyStore.java` class arises in the following code:

> Blockquote
>   From JDKKeyStore.java:
>   if (version != STORE_VERSION)
>           {
>               if (version != 0)
>               {
>                   throw new IOException("Wrong version of key store.");
>               }
>           }
>
> Blockquote

In this case STORE_VERSION = 1, and my version=3 based on reading the details of the certificate held by the keystore I have created.  I do not know how to generate a keystore containing a version=1 certificate.

I found this answer helpful: 
[wrong version keystore when doing https call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933103/wrong-version-keystore-when-doing-https-call)

however it calls for creating the keystore using the following parameters:

> -storetype BKS
>   -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
>   -providerpath /path/to/bouncycastle.jar

However, when I try to create the keytool (using the terminal app on Mac) using these parameters:

> keytool -genkeypair -v -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize
>   2048 -validity 10000 -keypass android -keystore
>   /Users/djames/dropbox/bc146keystore/debug.keystore -storepass android
>   -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider –providerpath /Users/djames/dropbox/bc146keystore/

(where /Users/djames/dropbox/bc146keystore/ is the path to the bouncy castle jar: bcprov-jdk16-146.jar)

I get the following error:

> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, ?providerpath
>   is not a legal command java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error,
>   ?providerpath is not a legal command  at
>   sun.security.tools.KeyTool.parseArgs(KeyTool.java:375)    at
>   sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:171)  at
>   sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)

I do not understand what this is telling me.  If I use: keytool -help it tells me that the following are valid options for the -genkeypair option:

> -genkeypair  [-v] [-protected]
>          [-alias ]
>          [-keyalg ] [-keysize ]
>          [-sigalg ] [-dname ]
>          [-validity ] [-keypass ]
>          [-keystore ] [-storepass ]
>          [-storetype ] [-providername ]
>          [-providerclass  [-providerarg ]] ...
>          [-providerpath ]

But in the Oracle docs java version 6 that I am using
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)
it tells me that these are the options:

> -genkeypair {-alias alias} {-keyalg keyalg} {-keysize keysize} {-sigalg sigalg} [-dname dname] [-keypass keypass] {-validity valDays}
>   {-storetype storetype} {-keystore keystore} [-storepass storepass]
>   {-providerClass provider_class_name {-providerArg provider_arg}} {-v}
>   {-protected} {-Jjavaoption}

which does not include the `-providerpath option`.  Why the discordance?
(If I do not use the -providerpath option, then I get an unknown class exception at the option: `"-providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"`...)

When I google: keytool -providerpath
I get nothing helpful to resolve this.

I am not sure how to solve my keystore version problem without solving my keytool problem.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Jim

```
(Mac OSX 10.6.8 if relevant)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong version of keystore on android call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117486/wrong-version-of-keystore-on-android-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get past this problem with the version of keystore.  see: [keytool error when creating BKS keystore: providerpath is not a legal command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015512/keytool-error-when-creating-bks-keystore-providerpath-is-not-a-legal-command/12135543#12135543)

Answer (score 14):

My problem was using a version of bouncy castle that was too new.  I had to use [146](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar) - any later and it gave me this error.

Comment: Same here, version 148 gives me the same error, thanks a lot!

Comment: This works, but I'm puzzled as to why Eclipse bundles a version (148) that doesn't work...

Comment: Using an old version of bouncycastle sucks. You could also simply chose the **BKS-V1** format instead of **BKS** as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33197845/5459467

Answer (score 1):

The version mismatch is for the key store version, not the certificate version (which should have the value 2 for a v3 X.509 certificate).

What version of the JDK did you use `keytool` from? Did you specify a full path to the command, or use what was in your `PATH`? Are you sure that you are using JKS key stores, and not JCEKS stores?

Comment: 1) not sure exactly how to tell the version of keytool I am using.    I am using Java SE runtime enviroment = 1.6.0_33, and presumably the corresponding JDK that goes with it (since I did not perform any separate installation that I know of). Based on my $PATH the keytool I am using comes out of the following subdirectory:  System/Library/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A.  I don't know why it doesn't come out of the:  .../JavaVM.framework /Versions/1.6.0  subdirectory…

Comment: 2) I did not specify a path but rather used the default.  As stated above, the default path would find keytool in: System>Library/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A.   When I do specify a path and run "System>Library/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/keytool -help" it shows me the same display as my default keytool, i.e. -genkeypair includes the option for -providerpath.

Comment: 3) Keystore type:  first I was playing around with the default debug.keystore that is created for android when you use Eclipse for your IDE.  When I encountered issues, I created my own keystore using keytool as previously described.  I did not specify any storetype when I did that so I would presumably get the default  type. Is there a way to display this?

Comment: I was able to verify that I am creating JKS key stores with my keytool (using the keytool -list command).

Comment: This seems to be a correct answer to one of my questions.  I think I asked to many questions at once, since I still can't create an appropriate keystore...

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete Ryan answer as I had to dig in to find out how to generate a BKS with Bouncy Castle 1.46, you can use [Portecle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/) to generate the BKS.

1. Download [Boucycastle Provider 1.46](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.46)
2. Install or unzip it.
3. Replace bcprov.jar in your Portecle install directory (example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Portecle\bcprov.jar`). Same naming is required.
4. Restart Portecle and generate your BKS truststore.

This explained [here](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/spocs/eSafe/trunk/WP_Supplemental/Cert_Inspect_Portecle-1.7/README.txt).

---

**Edit**:

Since Portecle 1.8, you can use BKS-V1 type to generate your truststore without to replace `bcprov.jar`.

You can select it after clicking on `New keystore` or change the type via the menu `Tools -> Change KeyStore Type`.

Comment: Since Portecle v1.8 you can simply select BKS-V1 in the "New KeyStore" dialog or convert between BKS and BKS-V1 via "Tools -> Change KeyStore Type". No need to replace jars.